# Jetty Hightide - war does not get unpacked

Tags: jetty

I have an installation of jetty hightide (rpm, version 8).
The server runs fine (seems to unpack all the test wars that are bundled with it) but for some reason it will not unpack any of my wars (or any other war for that matter). Restarting the service does not change this so it's not an auto-deploy issue.
Does anyone have any ideas as to what's causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The jetty rpm's and debs are...of questionable use to be honest.  I would highly recommend looking at the Fedora rpm's as they are doing a proper job of building rpm's for jetty 8 and jetty 9.  We should probably just stop releasing them altogether.  If you do get it sorted out then let me know!

Based on what you describe, I would check out the start.ini file, it is probably missing the jetty-webapps.xml and assumes you are doing a context deployment (ie jetty-contexts.xml is likely active).